# "Better" approach to ignoring classes when using code first and the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I am currently doing the following to remove any EF classes I don't want included. But this means I have to list all the classes.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder AModelBuilder)
{
    // Remove any classes that we don't want in the database. These are our derived classes
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TCompetition>();
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TCompeitionLadder>();
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TCompeitionPersonRole>();
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TCountry>();
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TSport>();
    AModelBuilder.Ignore<TVenue>();
}
```

So instead I thought I would use reflection to get the list of types in the assembly and then remove any class references that I don't want included. However I cannot seem to get this to work as the **Type** object is not the expected class reference type needed by Ignore(). Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder AModelBuilder)
{
     // Remove any classes that we don't want in the database. These are our derived classes
    Assembly objAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (Type objType in objAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (objType.BaseType.FullName.StartsWith("TEntityFramework", true, null))
        {
            AModelBuilder.Ignore<objType>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection to call the generic function,

Instead of writing this:

```
AModelBuilder.Ignore<objType>();
```

Write this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Ignore");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(objType);
generic.Invoke(AModelBuilder, null);
```

Comment: I get an error of:

The type or namespace name 'AModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

for the:

MethodInfo method = typeof(AModelBuilder).GetMethod("Ignore");

Comment: My mistake. I misunderstood your types, I edited the code, test the new one